# How to print the values of two dimensional pair vector?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, fstream

I have a text file with 4 rows and 3 columns

```
(0.165334,0) (0.166524,-0.0136064) (-0.144899,0.0207161)
(0.205171,0) (0.205084,-0.0139042) (-0.205263,0.0262445)
(0.216684,0) (0.215388,-0.0131107) (-0.193696,0.0251303)
(0.220137,0) (0.218849,-0.0135667) (-0.194153,0.025175)
```

I wrote following code to print the values of `FFTfile`. The script does not throw any errorm but it does not print the values. Any idea whats wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

class Point
{
public:
  double x;

  double y;

  friend istream& operator>>(istream& input, Point& p);
  friend ostream& operator<<(istream& s, Point& p);

  double getX(void);

  double getY(void);


};

  double Point::getX(void){
      return x;
      }

  double Point::getY(void){
      return y;
      }

istream& operator>>(istream& input, Point& p)
{
  char c;
  input >> c; // Read open parenthesis
  input >> p.x;
  input >> c; // Read comma
  input >> p.y;
  input >> c; // Read closing parenthesis

  return input;
};

ostream& operator<<( ostream& s, Point& p)
{
    s << p.getX() << ", " << p.getY();
    return s;
} 

vector<vector<Point> > LoadFFT(string path){
    string Filename;   
    vector<vector<Point> > matrix;  
    Filename.append(path);                                                                  
    Filename.append("....txt"); 
    ifstream fileFFT(Filename.c_str());
    string raw_text;
    while(getline(fileFFT, raw_text)){

        vector<Point> row;
        istringstream(raw_text);
        Point p;
        while( raw_text >> p ){
            row.push_back(p);

        }

    matrix.push_back(row);
    }

return(matrix);
}

int main(){
    vector<vector<Point> > FFTfile=LoadFFT("...");

    for (int i = 0; i < FFTfile.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < FFTfile[i].size(); j++){
            cout << FFTfile[i][j];
        }

    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: you never test if the opening of a file succeeded. How can you be sure that the file was actually opened?

Comment: I am just a noob man !! with less than a month  in C/C++experience, can you be of some help ?

Comment: your lack of experience does not entitle you to be treated differently. I suggested checking if the file opening succeeded. Have you tried checking if your program works with it?

Comment: **Start with something small and simple that works perfectly, then build up.** Have you tried writing a program that reads *one* number?

Comment: FWIW: It's a good time to start leaning which includes you need and which you don't. In this example you need fewer than half of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file opened successfully, one issue seems to be the following set of lines:

```
    istringstream(raw_text);
    Point p;
    while( raw_text >> p )
```

You have not created a `std::istringstream` object at the point where you are issuing the `>>` call.  Instead a temporary object was created and immediately destroyed.

This should be:

```
    istringstream strm(raw_text);
    Point p;
    while( strm >> p )
```

Having said this, I'm surprised the code compiled with no errors.

Comment: With you on the surprise. Still trying to figure that one out. It looks like `istringstream(raw_text);` is sort-of being seen as a `istringstream raw_text;`  and allowing compilation. Example: https://godbolt.org/g/CTcWw6 Why, I'll leave to folk who grok the nitty gritty of the language better than I do.

Comment: Strange, as here is the OP's code (with some changes), [compiled successully](https://godbolt.org/g/kXWsvb).

Comment: @bezet waiting to see if someone who does grasp what's going on drops by here. Paul, I'm pretty sure it's the deeper scope that allows it to compile. No collision with `voop` here: https://godbolt.org/g/3ye3Ti .

Comment: Yes. It's definitely the scope that allows it to compile, still `istringstream(raw_text)` being a valid(and non temporary variable) is confusing. I asked about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45991094/which-part-of-the-c-standard-allow-to-declare-variable-in-parenthesis).

Comment: @user4581301 I think it's a redefinition of a `raw_text` variable.

Comment: @Ron It is. No doubt about it. Took a while, but I finally got it. `istringstream(raw_text)` is `istringstream raw_text;`, but not `istringstream raw_text(previous_incarnation_of_raw_text);`, so it's an empty `istringstream` and all the `input >> blah`s fail unchecked with EOF. A cautionary tail about why one should always check your input.

Comment: @user4581301 or the advantages of compiling with `-Wshadow`

Comment: Yep, I see it now.  I had a sense that it had to do with variables being shadowed, but didn't identify it by sight.

Answer (score 1):

You don't load a file. Your call to: `LoadFFT("...")` functions results in a file name of: **.......txt** which is not a valid file name. The stringstream variable (re)definition is wrong, intermediary strings are not needed, nor their `c_str()` counterparts. The distilled `LoadFFT()` function is:

```
vector<vector<Point>> LoadFFT(const char* path){
    vector<vector<Point> > matrix;
    ifstream fileFFT(path);
    string raw_text;
    while (getline(fileFFT, raw_text)){
        vector<Point> row;
        istringstream iss(raw_text);
        Point p;
        while (iss >> p){
            row.push_back(p);
        }
        matrix.push_back(row);
    }
    return(matrix);
}
```

The modified `main()` function to allow for the new line after each row:

```
int main(){
    vector<vector<Point> > FFTfile = LoadFFT("myfile.txt");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < FFTfile.size(); i++){
        for (size_t j = 0; j < FFTfile[i].size(); j++){
            cout << FFTfile[i][j];
        }
        cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

These headers you need:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
```

You can remove the others.

Answer (score 1):

you're using raw_text (string) as as input parameter of type istream. I don't think such conversion is possible.
try using istringstream return value as the parameter for "<<" or change your code so that you copy from the file directly to your matrix.

edit: comments above have done better job explaining it