# Which part of the C++ standard allow to declare variable in parenthesis?

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
int main() {
    int(s);
}
```

I am surprised by the fact that it creates valid variable `s`. Can anyone explain what's happening here?

Comment: Same reason why both `return(0);` and `return 0;` work.

Comment: Some complicated type definitions are *required* to use parentheses to declare, so that the relevant modifiers are grouped properly. Redundant parentheses are generally ignored.

Comment: It works with non-primitives too.

Comment: I think you need a better example or a link back to [the question that spawned this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45990714/how-to-print-the-values-of-two-dimensional-pair-vector) to get the answer we are both really interested in.

Comment: @HenriMenke actually it is not the same reason. `0` is an expression but `s` in OP's code is a declarator

Comment: @HenriMenke: `return` takes an expression, and `(expression)` is also an expression. But `int (s)` is a definition, not an expression. I.e. _not_ the same reason. Cf.  `return 0+0` works but `int s+0` does not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of a declaration like int (x); or int (x) = 10;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26832321/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-declaration-like-int-x-or-int-x-10)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[dcl.meaning] in the Standard says:

> In a declaration `T D` where `D` has the form `( D1 )` the type of the contained *declarator-id* is the same as that of the contained *declarator-id* in the declaration `T D1`.
>
> Parentheses do not alter the type of the embedded *declarator-id*, but they can alter the binding of complex declarators.

More simply, you can put parentheses around anything considered a "declarator" in the C++ grammar.  (Loosely speaking, a declarator is a part of a declaration without the initial specifiers and types which contains one name.)

In your example, the identifier `s` is a declarator, so you're allowed to put parentheses around it and the meaning doesn't change.

The reason for this, as the second quoted sentence hints, is that it can be necessary when things get more complicated.  One example:

```
int * a [10];     // a is an array of ten pointers to int.
int ( * b ) [10]; // b is a pointer to an array of ten ints.
```

Comment: Nice one. I was going to give the OP a reference to the grammar summary instead.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to the other answers; in the grammar summary for declarators (C++14 [dcl.decl]/4) you can find:

```
ptr-declarator:
    noptr-declarator

noptr-declarator:
    ( ptr-declarator )
```

(I have omitted other details of the grammar).  You can see from this that any declarator may be parenthesized and it would still match the same grammar rule.