# What is the difference between typedef int array[3] and typedef int(array)[3]?

Tags: c++, arrays, typedef

I recently came across this unorthodox way to define a int array type:

```
typedef int(array)[3];
```

At first I thought it was an array of function pointers but then I realized that the `*` and the `()` were missing, so by looking into the code I deduced the type array was a `int[3]` type instead. I normally would declare this type as:

```
typedef int array[3];
```

Unless I'm mistaken that they are not the same thing, what is the advantage of doing so in the former way other than to make them look similar to a function pointer?

Comment: mater of taste (aka opinion based). imho the first version has a better visual separation between the alias (`array`)  and the aliased type (`int[3]`)

Comment: This is definitively a matter of taste, since the first way for me looks confusing since it looks like a function pointer at first glance.

Comment: From a pure semantic perspective, they are the same. The only difference is that the parentheses will change how the declarator is parsed (hence the placement of an asterisk can produce different types). Everything else is just as tobi said.

Comment: Use `using array = int[3];`

Comment: Nearly the same question, except for the `typedef`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45991094

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> What is the difference between `typedef int array[3]` and `typedef int(array)[3]`?

They are the same.

---

Parentheses could be used when a pointer is being declared, with `*`, and result in different types. In that case, parentheses could affect the precedence of `[]` or `int`. However, this is not your case here.

Answer (score 7):

These are both equivalent.  The parentheses do not alter the precedence of `[]` or `int` in this case.

The tool [cdecl](https://cdecl.org/) helps to confirm this:

- `int (a)[3]` gives "declare a as array 3 of int"
- `int a[3]` gives "declare a as array 3 of int"

Comment: Your answer seems more explicative for me since includes the tip of the using the tool cdecl. Thanks for it!

Comment: `cdecl` tool fails some time so better to not use it.

Comment: @haccks I'll bet it fails far less often than the programmers who need to use it.

Comment: @GabrielDiego I'm wondering why you accepted the other answer if you found this one more useful...

Answer (score -1):

If you run this code like this:

```
typedef int array[6];

array arr={1,2,3,4,5,6};
for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
     cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
```

And now you run this code like this:

```
typedef int (array)[6];
array arr={1,2,3,4,5,6};
for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
     cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
```

Both of those two types of code it generates the same output.This proves that both are same and the parentheses have no effect.

Comment: This can't be taken as a correct answer since they could be working the same by chance only while there could be other cases it does not. The answer is that they are the same but the reason is another than the one stated.

Comment: Most probably i could not understand your queries properly.