# Why doesn't this enum convert to int?

Tags: c++, enums

Why does the following code not compile under g++ (C++14), MSVC (C++14), or ARM (C++03)?

The named Error instance calls the integer constructor, but the anonymous Error instance does not resolve.

```
class Error
{
public:
    Error(int err) : code_(err) {}
    const int code_;
};

enum Value
{
    value_1
};

int main()
{
    // compiles
    Error e(value_1);

    // does not compile under G++, ARM, or MSVC
    Error(value_1);
}
```

Example error under G++: ([Coliru link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d397d806b227432))

`g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out`

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:19:18: error: no matching function for call to 'Error::Error()'
     Error(value_1);
                  ^
main.cpp:4:5: note: candidate: Error::Error(int)
     Error(int err) : code_(err) {}
     ^~~~~
main.cpp:4:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
main.cpp:1:7: note: candidate: constexpr Error::Error(const Error&)
 class Error
       ^~~~~
main.cpp:1:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
main.cpp:1:7: note: candidate: constexpr Error::Error(Error&&)
main.cpp:1:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Comment: Edited title: there is no **cast** in this code; the question is about a **conversion**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which part of the C++ standard allow to declare variable in parenthesis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45991094/which-part-of-the-c-standard-allow-to-declare-variable-in-parenthesis)

Comment: Without the both of you specifying which compiler it did/didn't work on, the report isn't interesting. It may be an extension, but I didn't analyse the grammar yet.

Comment: @DevSolar `Value::value_1` is non-standard as this is not a `class enum`.

Comment: Use `Error{value_1};`

Comment: @Ivan It *is* standard. Qualified enumerators are allowed even for old-style enums; see the C++11 standard [dcl.enum](10).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This comes from the same place as "The Most Vexing Parse" - the rule that if it can be a declaration, it *is* a declaration.
And surprisingly, you're allowed to put parentheses around the identifier in a variable declaration.
(I have no idea why, but I'm guessing that it simplified C's parser back in the day.)

The following are all valid declarations of `int` variables:

```
int (foo);
int (bar) = 0;
int (baz)(3);
int (twaddle)(baz);
```

Comment: Why parentheses are allowed is explained in K&R.

Comment: [WP:Most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

Comment: @Ivan Do you have a link/citation for the specific part of K&R in question?

Comment: @JAB No, but it the part that explains how type definitions work. Mentioned in my answer.

Comment: In some declarations, like a function pointer `int* (*f)();`, you need the parentheses to keep the stars associated with the right name.  So they are allowed. There are just no rules saying when you must *not* use them, so they can be added whenever you like.

Comment: And that's one reason for *uniform initialization*. Don't use parens here anymore!

Answer (score 37):

The problem is that code

```
Error(value_1);
```

is a declaration of a variable `value_1` of type `Error`.

This is a legacy from C language that uses expressions as part of type declaration.

For example `int *i` is a pointer to `int` because it says that expression `*i` should evaluate to type `int`. More examples of this:

- `int (*func)()` is a pointer to function returning `int` because expression `(*func)()` evaluates to type `int`.
- `int *p[8]` is an array of pointers to `int` because expression `*p[x]` evaluates to type `int`.
- `int (*p)[8]` is a pointer to array of 8 `int`'s (`int[8]`) because expression `(*p)[x]` evaluates to type `int`.
- `int (*(*p[8])())()` is an array of 8 pointers to functions returning pointers to a function returning `int` because expression `(*(*p[x])())()` evaluates to type `int`.

Similarly `int (i)` is a plain variable of type `int` as expression `(i)` evaluates to type `int`.

And so because C++ inherits this from C, it uses parenthesis as part of type declaration, but also adds more syntax on top, leading to some unexpected results.

The rule applied by C++ here says to treat everything that can be a declaration as a declaration.

---

Similar confusion if often caused by code like this:

```
Error ec();
```

which is a forward declaration of a function `ec` that returns `Error`.

Answer (score 14):

> main.cpp:19:18: error: no matching function for call to 'Error::Error()'
>       Error(value_1);

The compiler tries to call the non-existent default constructor `Error::Error()` because it sees

```
Error(value_1);
```

as a variable declaration

```
Error  value_1;
```

A declaration is allowed to have redundant parenthesis.