# why is this a variable definition?

Tags: c++

See this code snippet below

```
int main()
{
 int(i);
 int(j)=6;
}
```

What does that mean?This code snippet could be compiled without error,and the code hinter shows that `i,j` are both variable of type `int`.
As far as i'm concerned,only those definitions like `int i;int j=6;` are legal and consistent with the syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which part of the C++ standard allow to declare variable in parenthesis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45991094/which-part-of-the-c-standard-allow-to-declare-variable-in-parenthesis)