# C++ pointers objects difference

Tags: c++, pointers, declaration, variable-declaration, function-declaration

Can somebody explain me the difference between the following?

1. Those two

```cpp
float *pointer[10];

float *(pointer[10]);
```

2. and those two

```cpp
int(*pointer_function)();

int *pointer_function();
```

Comment: FWIW: [here](https://cdecl.org/) is a handy website to figure out some of the gibberish

Comment: Me thinks 1. is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45991094/which-part-of-the-c-standard-allow-to-declare-variable-in-parenthesis and 2. is easy becuase those are quite different things, "pointer to a function" and "a function returning pointer (`int*`)".

Comment: Would highlight this is why many people prefer `float* pointer[10]` rather than `float *pointer[10]` because the `float*` is the type

Comment: @UKMonkey Many people prefer float * pointer[10]; :)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow it's better than `float   <many spaces that get edited out here>      *pointer[10]` when someone's trying to line up their variable names!

Answer (score 3):

These two declarations

```
float *pointer[10];

float *(pointer[10]);
```

are equivalent. You can write even the following way

```
float *( ( pointer )[10] );
```

That is it is a declaration of an array of 10 pointers to float.

These declarations

```
int(*pointer_function)();

int *pointer_function();
```

are different. The first one declares a pointer to a function of type `int()`. The second one declares a function (not a pointer to a function) with type `int *()`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

int * pointer_function() // #1
{
    static int x = 1'000'000;

    return &x;
};

int f1() // #2
{
    return 2'000'000;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << *pointer_function() /* calling #1 */<< '\n';

    int( *pointer_function )() = f1;

    std::cout << pointer_function() /* calling #2 */ << '\n';


    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1000000
2000000
```

To make more obvious the difference between the declarations you can rewrite the second declaration (that is the declaration of function) the following way

```
int * ( pointer_function )();
```

Compare it with the pointer to function declaration

```
int ( *pointer_function )();
```

Take into account that a declarator may be enclosed in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Always keep in mind the place of Parentheses.  Parentheses do not alter the type of the object, but they can alter the binding of complex declarators.

From above code snippet:

```cpp
float *pointer[10];// Array of 10 pointer to float

float *(pointer[10]); //bracket around array of 10 pointer to float, So same as above

int(*pointer_function)(); // function pointer to achieve callbacks

int * pointer_function(); // function to integer pointer
```