# Can't pass lvalue to construct an rvalue

Tags: c++

Is there anyone who can help explain why `UseString` in my following example cannot accept an lvalue as a parameter? I know a temporary `String` is created in my case, but I cannot explain why it has to accept an rvalue here.

```
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

struct String
{
    String(const char* cstr)
    {
    }
};

struct UseString
{
    UseString(const String& str)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    const char* cstr = "abc";
    UseString(std::move(cstr)); //Correct
    UseString("abc"); // Correct
    UseString(cstr); // Error but why UseString cannot accept lvalue as parameter in this case?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the ampersand operater takes it to the address of str in struct UseString and the variable has no address declared so lvalues are not considered.

Comment: What do you think `UseString("abc");` does?

Comment: is case 3 give an error?

Comment: when you think you know c++ case like this come up... const & suppose to take anything and String suppose to be constructed from anything. also std::move does not move anythig, so cstr should be intact.

Comment: @Nick [OPs MCVE on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be0c24ba37db9be6)

Comment: IMHO, the complaints of g++ are quite literal and precise. (I must admit that I didn't see the issue before.)

Comment: Yes once I saw the error of the compiler I got it ;)

Comment: Slightly vexing parse strikes again

Comment: `"abc"` is an lvalue by the way.

Comment: [Why are string literals l-value while all other literals are r-value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004511/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is because `UseString(cstr);` does not do what you think it does.

It is actually a **variable declaration**, not a **constructor call**. It is treated exactly the same as `UseString cstr;` And `cstr` was already declared earlier, hence the error.

See [Which part of the C++ standard allow to declare variable in parenthesis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45991094/)

Per this [Live Demo](https://ideone.com/gMLgG0):

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:24:16: error: conflicting declaration ‘UseString cstr’
    UseString(cstr);
                  ^

prog.cpp:21:14: note: previous declaration as ‘const char* cstr’
    const char* cstr = "abc";
                ^~~~
```

There is no way the compiler can confuse `UseString(std::move(cstr));` and `UseString("abc");` as variable declarations, so they are treated as calls to the constructor instead.

To solve this, you can use curly braces instead of parenthesis:

```cpp
UseString{std::move(cstr)};
UseString{"abc"};
UseString{cstr};
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/6hKdH1)

Comment: Here is another working example `UseString(String{cstr});`

Comment: @Nick right, because it can't be confused as a variable declaration