# Conflicting declaration when passing file stream to constructor

Tags: c++, file, class, constructor

I'm trying to make 2 constructors to a class, where one opens the file, checks for errors, and calls the other one. But I can't get it to work. I get the error:

> Conflicting declaration 'A file'

Can I not call a constructor inside another one? I always thought I could.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class A {
  int a = 0;
public:
  A()=default;
  explicit A(char *filename);
  explicit A(std::ifstream &file);
};

A::A(char *filename) {
  std::ifstream file(filename);

  if(!file.is_open()) {
    std::cout << "ERROR!\n";
    A();
    return;
  }

  A(file); // Compilation error here

  file.close();
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Can I not call a constructor inside another one?*  **No**, that'd make a different object that is anonymous and gets destructed at the `;`.  Better to have a *factory function* that does all that heavy lifting and figures out what's what and then constructs the object appropriately.

Comment: When you do `A();` or `A(file);` you do not actually initialize `this` object. Instead you create a brand new, independent and unrelated object. Which will immediately reach its end of life and be destroyed.

Comment: On another couple of notes, first please *always* include the actual error you get when asking questions about build errors. Preferably copy-paste (as text) the full and complete build-log for the code shown. Then I recommend that you don't use specific stream types as arguments. Instead of `std::ifstream` as argument use `std::istream`. Then you can use *any* input stream, like for example `std::cin`.

Comment: Also I recommend that the constructors do as little as possible work, only the bare minimum needed to get the object into a workable state. For everything else use independent functions that needs to be called after construction.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude does after construction mean at the end of the constructor or? In this case I'm trying to get the information from a file and put it in the parameter, so I would say thats the bare minimum.

Comment: I really suggest you do all file-operations on an already constructed object. Perhaps by overloading the stream "input" operator `>>`? Again, that will allow you to use any kind of stream, not only files. If you want to couple it more tightly to the object, or rather the class, then perhaps a `static` "read" function (which can use an overloaded `>>` operator).

Comment: By separating construction and reading data, you make things much simpler and less error prone. For example reading a file could throw an exception, which isn't nice when doing object construction. It's also better for both testing, debugging and maintenance to keep things as simple and separate as possible.

Comment: Related, almost dupe: [Can I call a constructor from another constructor (do constructor chaining) in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/308276) (The difference is that the current question isn't "chaining" in the sense of the other question. You would need a helper function to transform the `char *` to `std::ifstream &file` in order to make a chain.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I not call a constructor inside another one? I always thought I could.

You can, but not the way you are trying to.

In your example, the compiler is treating this statement:

`A(file);`

The same as if you had written this instead:

`A file;`

(see [Which part of the C++ standard allow to declare variable in parenthesis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45991094/which-part-of-the-c-standard-allow-to-declare-variable-in-parenthesis))

But, you already have an existing variable named `file`, hence the conflict.

*Delegating constructors* only work in the **member initialization list**, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class A {
  int a = 0;
public:
  A() = default;
  explicit A(char *filename);
  explicit A(std::ifstream &file);
};

A::A(char *filename) :
  A(std::ifstream(filename)) {
}

A::A(std::ifstream &file) : A() {
  if (!file.is_open()) {
    std::cout << "ERROR!\n";
  }
}

int main()
{
    A a("file.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

However, that won't work in your example since you can't take a non-const reference to a temporary object.  So, you will have to break out the stream operations into a separate method that both constructors can call, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class A {
  int a = 0;
  void doSomething(std::ifstream &file);
public:
  A() = default;
  explicit A(char *filename);
  explicit A(std::ifstream &file);
};

A::A(char *filename) : A() {
  std::ifstream file(filename);

  if (!file.is_open()) {
    std::cout << "ERROR!\n";
    return;
  }

  doSomething(file);
}

A::A(std::ifstream &file) : A() {
  doSomething(file);
}

A::doSomething(std::ifstream &file) {
  ... 
}

int main()
{
    A a("file.txt");
    return 0;
}
```