# How do overload an assignment operator that sums two instance variable of a class?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

The detailed discussion of the problem is shown in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45990714/how-to-print-the-values-of-two-dimensional-pair-vector/45991023#45991023). I am trying to sum up two instance variable defined inside class `Point` and assign it to a different variable `temp`.

```
class Point{
    public:
      double x;  
      double y;       
      friend istream& operator>>(istream& input, Point& p);
      double operator=(Point& p);      
      double getSqX(void);      
      double getSqY(void);
      double LengthSquared(void);  


    };    
      double Point::getSqX(void){
          return pow(x,2);}

      double Point::getSqY(void){
          return pow(y,2);}

       double Point::LengthSquared(){ return getSqX() + getSqY(); }


    istream& operator>>(istream& input, Point& p){
     ... // over load the >> operator      
      return input;
    };


     int main(){
        double temp;        
        vector<vector<Point> > FFTfile= some function that loads data();        
        for (int i = 0; i < FFTfile.size(); i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < FFTfile[i].size(); j++){
                 temp=FFTfile[j].LengthSquared();            
            }           

        }       
        return(0);
}
```

Edit:
Based on the suggestions,  I created a method LengthSquared(), but I still get following error:

```
 error: 'class std::vector<Point>' has no member named 'LengthSquared'  temp=FFTfile[j].LengthSquared();
```

Comment: Hi, check out the answers from Peer and Martin, also for clarity purpose the assignment operator in c++ looks like this `class_name & class_name :: operator= ( class_name )` (SRC: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment). I'm guessing that you just mixed your approach. This should look like this "`Point Point::operator=(Point& p)`" or "`double Point::operator=(Point& p)`" - not recommended.

Comment: I think that's the most abusive operator abuse I've seen. You would need to to write `Point p; Point p2; double x = p = p2;` to get the sum of `p2`'s squares into `x`, and you would be unable to assign one `Point` to another. I don't think you actually want to do this.

Comment: @Spandy why would you even want to do this? Overloading the assignment operator to do something that has absolutely nothing to with assignments is just making your code needlessly unreadable without gaining anything.

If you really really want this to be an operator, at least use a different one than `operator=`.

Comment: If what you actually want is `Point p; double d = p;`, you can create a conversion operator. It's still seriously confusing, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never overload the assignment operator this way. Someone reading your code will be confused, since assignment normally means .. assign value to object.

Instead, create a method like this

```
double Point::LengthSquared() { return getSqX() + getSqY(); }
```

Comment: Would I need to call FFTfile[j].LengthSquared() to get the squared sum?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea.

Comment: I get the following   error: 'class std::vector<Point>' has no member named 'LengthSquared()'. The error is on this line  temp=FFTfile[j].LengthSquared();

Comment: You forgot the index "[i]". You probably mean temp = FFTfile[i][j].LengthSqueared();

Answer (score 0):

an assignment-operator should have the following interface:

```
Point& operator=(const Point& other);
```

or

```
Point& operator=(const AnotherType& other);
```

to allow assignments of other types.

You are abusing the assignment operator. Use a regular method.

Comment: How would returning object of type Point help though? Would I be able to assign the output from "operation=" to a float variable ?

Comment: The point is, that you should not use the assignment operator for this. Create a regular Method. Peer gave you an example.LengthSquared()

Comment: @Spandy how would that even look (assigning the output of `operator=` to a float).

Do you want it Like this: 
`float f = pointA = pointB` ? Because don't do that, its completely unreadable and confusing. Also, you can't overload `=` like that, use a different operator if you absolutely must.